# Does recursion in the C preprocessor abuse an inconsistency in the standard?

Tags: c++, c, language-lawyer, c-preprocessor

Consider this code:

```
#define MAP_OUT

#define A(x) B MAP_OUT (x)
#define B(x) A MAP_OUT (x)

A(x)
```

Then `A(x)` expands to `B MAP_OUT (x)`, then `B (x)`. Now take a look at the standard:

> After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted and # and ## processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing tokens are removed. The resulting preprocessing token sequence is then rescanned, along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the source file, for more macro names to replace.

Does `B (x)` belong to *"resulting preprocessing token sequence for more macro names to replace"*? All compilers I have tried don't expand `B (x)` during a single scan, but what about the standard itself?

Comment: The text you've quoted seems to say "yes". Do you have another interpretation that you think applies?

Comment: Some people say that the C preprocessor first sees `B`, this is not an invocation yet, then `MAP_OUT`, which expands to nothing, and then `(x)`, which stays as it was, e.g. the preprocessor doesn't look behind after all the replacement list has been rescanned.

Comment: @KamilCuk Not sure. g++ handled `A (x)` like `A(x)`. (I fiddled a bit and tried to remember how this blue-painting stuff actually works... [**Fiddling on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25a78bf5322cc053))

Comment: @KamilCuk - valid point, but it is still true that if attempting to invoke either form ( `B (x)` or `B(x)` ) _implicit declaration  of `A` is not valid_ will prevent a compile.

Comment: @KamilCuk, it seems that the space between a macro name and the parentheses doesn't play any role, since I can both invoke `FOO(123)` and `FOO (123)`.

Comment: `B` isn't a valid macro at the point where `A` is expanded. So `B` is just some valid but unknown pre-proc token and `(x)` is `x` surrounded by parenthesis, not a macro invocation of `B(x)`. And so it won't compile.

Comment: Yet another confusing example: https://godbolt.org/z/oGE5KG. E.g. after `CAT(I, D)` has been expanded, the preprocessor "looks behind" when it sees `(123)` and then expands `ID(123)` to `123`. This behaviour of "looking behind" doesn't work for the initial example with `MAP_OUT`...

Comment: @Lundin it seems that GCC and Clang handle my example in this manner. But anyway I have a feeling that the standard itself doesn't define the exact way it has to be preprocessed.

Comment: At least, I remembered where I read about the "blue-painting"... [Is the C preprocessor Turing complete?](http://pfultz2.com/blog/2012/05/10/turing/) (Once, I became retired I will take the time to understand this fully...) ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does B (x) belong to "resulting preprocessing token sequence for more macro names to replace"?

No, absolutely not. Read again:

> After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted and # and ## processing has taken place, all placemarker preprocessing tokens are removed. The resulting preprocessing token sequence is then rescanned.

The preprocessing token sequence that results from parameter replacement `in A(x)` is precisely `B MAP_OUT (x)`, nothing more, nothing less. This sequence is then scanned for more macros to replace, once. There is only one eligible macro to replace in there, `MAP_OUT`. Then the replacement of `MAP_OUT`is scanned, nothing is found, and the processing is resumed.

There is no indication whatsoever that `B` in `B MAP_OUT (x)` should be scanned twice.

Comment: Consider this example: https://godbolt.org/z/oGE5KG. If we follow your logic, then the resulting preprocessing token sequence to be rescanned is `CAT(I, D)(123)`. The preprocessor sees `CAT(I, D)` and expands it to `ID`, then it sees `(123)`, which is just a parenthesised number, and rescanning stops. But accidentally, `ID(123)` then expands to `123`. Why?

Comment: @TemirkhanMyrzamadi "The resulting preprocessing token sequence is then rescanned, **along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the source file** .`CAT(I, D)` is replaced with `ID`, then `ID(123)` is scanned and replaced, because `ID(123)` is the "resulting preprocessing token sequence... along with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the source file".

Answer (score 3):

You're cherry-picking. The standard requires that rescanning and replacement stops.

There are other paragraphs, with identical wording in every C++ standard since C++98 (not just the one you've quoted) that *actually* control the behaviour you observe.

> After all parameters in the replacement list have been substituted, the resulting preprocessing token sequence is rescanned with all subsequent preprocessing tokens of the source file for more macro names to replace.
>
> If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file’s preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. Further, if any nested replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not replaced. These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no longer available for further replacement even if they are later (re)examined in contexts
> in which that macro name preprocessing token would otherwise have been replaced.

As I said, the wording is identical in every C++ standard.  Only the section and para numbers change.

- In C++98, the above quote is Section 16.3.4 "Rescanning and further replacement", paras 1 and 2;
- In C++17 the above quote is Section 19.3.4 "Rescanning and further replacement", paras 1 and 2;
- In the latest C++20 draft (at least, the latest I've accessed) the above quote is Section 15.6.4    "Rescanning and further replacement", paras 1 and 3  (there is an added para 2 with an illustrative example, not normative text).

Comment: I think the key is rather that pre-processing happens from top to bottom in the source file. Which isn't really defined anywhere as far as I can tell... And so the rescanning stops when only `B (x)` remains, both valid pre-proc tokens but neither a macro.

Comment: @Lundin In my [**Fiddling on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25a78bf5322cc053) I reverted the order of the `#define`s (just to be sure) but the outcome still was `B (x)`...

Comment: @Lundin +1. Actually if `B (x)` expands further to `A MAP_OUT (x)` during the same scan, then `A` will be blueprinted. But most compilers even stop at `B (x)`, and blueprinting doesn't occur.

Comment: Possibly related is C11 6.4/4 (the "maximal munch rule") which is about the only (implicit) hint I can find in the standard of left-to-right parsing. The examples given make it clearer, but they aren't normative.